# Using ustom GSON deserializer with derived classes

Tags: android, json, gson

I wanted to create some abstractions, so I would reduce amount of duplicated code.

Simple example (my real objects are much more complex - that's why I'm parsing it manually, but both B and C share a lot of data with A):

```
public abstract class A {
   int x;
   int y;
}

public class B extends A {
   int z;
}

public class C extends A {
   int w;
}
```

I have written two custom deserializers  and  and they both derive from some abstract deserializer which will take care of populating fields `x` and `y` of base class and then it should populate fields depending on certain class.

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(B.class, new BsonDeserializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(C.class, new CJsonDeserializer());
```

My problem is that Gson will be taking only superclass into account while registering, so it won't be using two different deserializers for two different classes, only the first one.

I'm aware of fact that there is RuntimeTypeAdapter class available, but AFAIK, it would force me to modify json on my server - let's say every JSON would contain field "type" (and I can't really do it - I'm not allowed to)(?)

Are there any good approaches to this kind of problem?